# ORACLE SQL- After delete trigger on parent table with cascade set null, mutating error workaround

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I am trying to update columns in my child table `service` after delete on parent table `cars` using function `choose_ideal_car` which uses some selects over `cars` and `service` tables.

Here is part of my sql script:

```
CREATE TABLE cars(car_id INT CONSTRAINT pk_id_cars);
CREATE TABLE service(
service_id INT CONSTRAINT pk_id_service PRIMARY KEY,
car_id INT CONSTRAINT fk_id_car REFERENCES cars(car_id) ON DELETE SET NULL,
period VARCHAR2(5) CONSTRAINT check_period CHECK period IN ('even','odd','every'),
period VARCHAR2(3) CONSTRAINT check_day CHECK day IN ('mon','tue','wed','thu','fri')
);
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER service_set_car_id AFTER DELETE ON cars
DECLARE
CURSOR touched_rows is select * from service where car_id = null;
touched_row service%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
OPEN touched_rows;
  LOOP
  FETCH touched_rows INTO touched_row;
  EXIT WHEN touched_rows%NOTFOUND;
  UPDATE service SET car_id = choose_ideal_car(touched_row.period,touched_row.day) WHERE service_id = touched_row.service_id;
  END LOOP;
CLOSE touched_rows;
end;
/
```

For some reason my trigger is never fired.

I also tried creating triggers like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER service_set_car_id AFTER DELETE FROM cars FOR EACH ROW
CURSOR touched_rows is select * from service where car_id = :old.car_id;
...
```

Which is fired but throws 'mutating error' because function `choose_ideal_car` uses selects from both tables. Maybe the solution of this is to create duplicate of my `cars` table and select from it in my `choose_ideal_car` function instead of selecting from the `cars` table on which is my trigger defined, but that does not sounds good to me.

While I am writing this post I realized that even if my first trigger is fired it would not work correctly and throw the same 'mutating error'.

So in the end I have two questions:

1) Why is the first trigger never fired?

2) How to fix this mutating error and get all working correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`where car_id = null` returns no rows, use `where car_id is null` instead

Comment: btw. when you do not make any extra action except the update in the loop, you can just have a single line instead of the cursor and loop: `UPDATE service SET car_id = choose_ideal_car(period,day) WHERE car_id IS NULL; `

Comment: oh.. that null comparison was really dumb mistake...


If I use this one-line update isn't it possible that the function is computed once and all updated rows will have the same value?
I choose the loop because the result of the function depends on values in `service` table so I wanted to be sure that the function will be computed for every row.

Comment: @JanTomášek the function will be calculated for each affected row